# How can Xamarin UITest launch apps with environment variables?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.uitest

I would like to override some defaults in the app under test so we can redirect network traffic.  How can I configure the platform configuration to set environment variables on the App under test?

For example, I have a default api endpoint and I'd like to pass a stub/mock endpoint url in to the application for the test run.  Then the mobile app would select the endpoint like the following.

```
var endpoint = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEST_API_ENDPOINT") ??  DEFAULT_ENDPOINT;
return new NetworkClient(nativeHttpHandler, BaseUrl.Create(endpoint));
```

And the UI Test could configure the stub API to return specific scenarios like locked out accounts or network outages or specific user data without having to modify data on a staging server to which my team doesn't have direct access.

Comment: Hi , could you explain more info about the environment variables ? Such as what variables .

Comment: You would have to use pre-build scripts to work environment variables https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/custom/scripts/